# measure of spatial shift

Tags: spatial

I need some advise on how to quantify the spatial shift of an event. I have current distribution of rice across a large region. Not everywhere in the region is rice present. Then I model this distribution and I project its future distribution which shows me that the rice area has moved more eastwards (along with some random distribution). If I want to show in a map the net movement of rice area from the current to future, what are the measures or variable that I can use?

In detail: all the areas where rice is present, I give them a value of 1 and areas where rice is absent, I give them a value of 0. Both my modelled current and future distribution are in 1 and 0s.

Comment: There are many good ones to choose from. What do you want your measure to describe about the rice distribution? How far east it has come at the leading edge? At the trailing edge? On average? Relative to food transportation systems? Inland?  *Etc., etc.*

Comment: @whuber I do know the meaning of leading or trailing edge in this context but anything that measures how far has it moved eastwards on average should be able to convey my message.

Comment: That looks like an answer to your own question. If you want to know the details of calculating an average position, you will find [several threads](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=population%20center) on [gis.se], such as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83022/.